# Name of midpoint rule and trapezoidal rule in higher dimension

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximate-integration

Consider the integral
$$ I = \int_0^a \int_0^b f(x,y)\,dy\,dx. $$

I can, in order to approximate the integral, use some kind of "trapezoidal rule"
$$ I \approx I_{\mathrm{tr}} = \frac{ab}4\bigl(f(0,0) + f(a,0) + f(a,b) + f(0,b)\bigr) $$
or use some kind of "midpoint rule"
$$ I \approx I_{\mathrm{mp}} = ab\cdot f\left(\frac{0+a}2,\frac{0+b}2\right). $$

Do these rules have specific names, maybe even their $n$-dimensional generalizations?

I think they should be accurate of second order:
$$ I - I_{\mathrm{tr}}, I - I_{\mathrm{mp}}\in\mathcal O\bigl((ab)^2\bigr) $$
is there a source that proves it (so I don't have to)?

Comment: Try under "finite element method" -- FEM.